# Adjust HTML table with content want to displayed, Angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, angular

My page is about showing data table from user on shift indicator.

[image]

My dashboard.component.html

```
<table class="table">
      <thead>
       <tr>
       <th *ngFor="let col of tablePresetColumns">
       {{col.content}}
       </th>
       <th></th>
       <th></th>
       </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
       <tr *ngFor="let row of tablePresetData ">
       <td *ngFor="let cell of row"> {{cell.content}}</td>
     <td *ngFor="let cell of row"> 
      <span class ="dot" [ngClass]="{
       'dot-yellow' : cell.content == 'Busy',
       'dot-green' : cell.content == 'Idle',
       'dot-red' : cell.content == 'Overload'}">
       </span>
     </td>
       </tr>
      </tbody>
  </table>
```

My example data :

```
  tablePresetColumns = [{ id: 1, content: "Username" }];
  tablePresetData = [
    [{ id: 1, content: "Adiet Adiet" }, { id: 2, content: "Idle" }],
    [{ id: 1, content: "Andri Irawan" }, { id: 2, content: "Idle" }],
    [{ id: 1, content: "Ari Prabudi" }, { id: 2, content: "Idle" }]
  ];
```

How should i do to :

> removes the status in the page that I want to display, so it just
>   appear username and color indicator

I've tried to change *ngFor into this (with index [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8fa8.png)) :

```
<td *ngFor="let cell of row"> {{cell.content[1]}}
```

but it didn't works at all
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
<td> {{row[0].content}}</td>
```

instead of

```
<td *ngFor="let cell of row"> {{cell.content[1]}}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th *ngFor="let col of tablePresetColumns">{{col.content}}</th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let row of tablePresetData">
      <ng-container *ngFor="let cell of row, let i = index">
        <td *ngIf="i == 0">{{cell.content}}</td>
        <td *ngIf="i == 0">
          <span
            [ngClass]="{
        'dot-yellow' : row[1].content == 'Busy',
        'dot-green' : row[1].content == 'Idle',
        'dot-red' : row[1].content == 'Overload'}"
          >
          </span>
        </td>
      </ng-container>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

See here for a live example: https://codesandbox.io/s/7y2r69992j

#### Note

I think your data structure is a but awkward and un-semantic. It would be better, if your data would look like this:

```
tablePresetColumns = ["Username", "Status"];
tablePresetData = [
  {username: "Adiet Adiet", status: "Idle"},
  {username: "Andri Irawan", status: "Busy" },
  {username: "Ari Prabudi", status: "Overload" }
];
```

So you could show the table like this

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th *ngFor="let col of tablePresetColumns">{{col}}</th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let row of tablePresetData">
      <td>{{ row.username }}</td>
      <td>
        <span [ngClass]="{
          'dot-yellow' : row.status == 'Busy',
          'dot-green' : row.status == 'Idle',
          'dot-red' : row.status == 'Overload'
        }">
        </span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Much easier to read and maintain.

Also a live example: https://codesandbox.io/s/o27pv052z

Answer (score 0):

You need to use .map on tablePresetData and have some changes on object structure
[image]

## **angular code here:**

```
tablePresetColumns: any = [
    {thTitle:"id", thWidth:'30px'}, 
    {thTitle:"Username", thWidth:'160px'},
    {thTitle:"Status", thWidth:'100px'},
    {thTitle:"", thWidth:'60px'}
];
tablePresetData: any = [
    { id: 1, Username: "Adiet Adiet", status: "Idle" },
    { id: 2, Username: "Andri Irawan", status: "Overload" },
    { id: 3, Username: "Ari Prabudi", status: "Busy" }
];

constructor() {}
ngOnInit() {

    this.tablePresetData.map((item: any) => {
        if (item.status === "Busy") {
        item["className"] = "dot-yellow";
        }
        if (item.status === "Idle") {
        item["className"] = "dot-green";
        }
        if (item.status === "Overload") {
        item["className"] = "dot-red";
        }
    });

    console.log("this.tablePresetData", this.tablePresetData);
}
```

## **Html code**

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th 
            *ngFor="let tableHd of tablePresetColumns" 
            [width]="tableHd.thWidth" >
                {{tableHd.thTitle}}
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let tableCol of tablePresetData">
            <td>{{tableCol.id}}</td>
            <td>{{tableCol.Username}}</td>
            <td>{{tableCol.status}}</td>
            <td>
                <span [ngClass]='tableCol.className' class="circle"></span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

## **CSS Class -**

```
.circle{border-radius: 10px; display: inline-block; height: 10px; width: 10px; }
.dot-yellow{background-color: yellow;}
.dot-green{background-color:green;}
.dot-red{background-color:red;}
```